# Is $\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k+1\right)\left(C^n_k\right)^2 = \frac{n+2}{2} C^{2n}_n$ for any positive integer $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Today I had a test about IMO which is pretty hard though, I have worked on a combinatoric question that I found a special formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k+1\right)\left(C^n_k\right)^2 = \dfrac{n+2}{2} C^{2n}_n$$
I don't know it is true or not, but it seems true because I have tested for some small $n$ and it is true. I have thought of using binomial theorem and breaking the $C^{n}_k$, but I still can't prove it. Luckily, I can do the question without using this formula, but I still someone can prove this formula. Tips and comments are welcome too.

Comment: Maybe this page can be of use: [Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k{n\choose k}^2 = n{2n-1 \choose n-1} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469559/proving-sum-k-0nkn-choose-k2-n2n-1-choose-n-1).

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth I think I know hoe to solve this if I get this identity. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Also related [Combinatorial coefficients squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061461)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2757215/299698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $[x^n]$ as the coefficient-extractor operator (it returns the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series of its argument) we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)\binom{n}{k}^2 =[x^n]\left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(k+1)x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)\right]$$
hence the LHS can be written as 
$$ [x^n]\left[(1+x)^n\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}\right]=[x^n]\left[(1+x)^n\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(x(1+x)^n\right)\right] $$
or as
$$ [x^n] \left[(1+x)^n\cdot\left((1+x)^n+nx(1+x)^{n-1}\right)\right]=[x^n](1+x)^{2n}+n[x^{n-1}](1+x)^{2n-1} $$
which, by the binomial theorem, equals
$$ \binom{2n}{n}+n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)\binom{2n}{n} $$
as is was to be shown.